# Always download tar.gz from pypi server

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I have local pypi server, where I download the packages from https://pypi.org/simple/

I ran command

```
pip install -d /srv/pypi/ cryptography==2.2.2
```

And it installed `cryptography-2.2.2-cp34-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl` in my local pypi server.

When I try to use that `pypi` server to download package on non linux platform, it fails.

Then I downloaded `cryptography-2.2.2.tar.gz` and put in local pypi, then it works fine.

How can I say in `pip install -d` command to always download `tar.gz` for that package ?

Comment: Have you tried `--no-binary` or `--no-use-wheel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the [`--no-binary`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#install-no-binary) flag.  To use sdist for cryptography:

```
pip install --no-binary cryptography cryptography
```

To use sdist for everything:

```
pip install --no-binary :all: cryptography
```

Comment: If we have to install binary, then is there any way to tell them to install for MAC, Linux and Win32 ?

Comment: pip will do that automatically based on the platform tags in the.whl filename

Comment: yes, but my pypi server is deployed on linux, and it install `.whl` for linux only. There are user, who use windows and mac and use our local pypi server.

Comment: it doesn't matter on what platform the index is hosted.  you upload  multiple wheels for all different platforms on your index, pip will choose the correct one to download for the client platform at install time.

Comment: I agree, but when I do `pip install -d /srv/pypi cryptography` it will install only `linux` wheel, because where I ran that command is `linux`, but I have to say that, please download for all platform in `/srv/pypi`

Comment: You should only install linux wheel for linux platform.  So, what's the problem? If you want to *download* other platform wheels, you can just `wget` or `curl` files from the index directly.

Comment: May be its my mistake, I not explain in question. I have local pypi server deployed on linux. We use that local pypi server for our local build, deployment. We have jenkins running on linux, so we dont have problem in that build. Some developer has Mac and Windows, when they try to run build locally, its gives error for package not found. For now, I am doing it manually, `wget` the package, but want to know, is there any way to give that platform in `pip install -d /srv/pypi` command ?

Comment: No, there is not.  You'll either need to upload bdist files for the Mac and Windows users too, or get them to use sdist / build locally.  If they build locally they need to install any build deps beforehand (development headers, C++ compilers, etc).

Comment: yes, I am facing that issue only :(. `cryptography` need `openssl.h`, and when upload the `tar.gz` for that package, it try to build and give error for that file. Is there any way to know the link for Mac or Windows? I can add that in my automated script, but dont want to do that manually. Like command `give me url for crytpography==2.2.2 for windows`

Comment: No. If you want to install from sdist you should do that part manually. And that's why it's better to build wheels for all the platforms you want and upload them to your index (because then users don't need to have the development headers).